# Google Chrome "Cannot set allocations"

Tags: google-chrome

When starting Google Chrome I often get this error. Other times Chrome just plain crashes. Why is this?

[image]

It happened in windows 8.1 pro too. Then I upgraded to windows 10 hoping it would fix it but it didn't.

I did a clean uninstall of Chrome and clean installed it - no luck.

I don't even have any extensions besides Adblock Plus.

My laptop has (gasp!) 32gigs of ram by the way. 8mb cache i7 with a gtx 880m and a 500gb SSD, so what gives?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new profile? Re-installing Chrome?

Comment: Might be relevant: [What is the "Cannot set allocations" error, who emits it and what can I do about it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2730990)

Comment: @DavidPostill yes. no luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730990/what-is-the-cannot-set-allocations-error-who-emits-it-and-what-can-i-do-about